# How can I use list variables globally in Razor C#

Tags: c#, razor

I'm now developing razor base text editor, all I want to do is once editor read the CSV data, use this data in following post action. It will be mean create global variables once open the page use that variables in full of programming source. I tried to this, however I need a reload csv files after post action How can I use once read csv data (list) globally like this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ARTFAQ.Pages
{

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    public string error;
    public List<Documents> doc1 = new List<Documents>();
    public string indx;
    public string evnt;
    public string evnt2;
    public string bodyelement;
    public string htmldata;
    public string textdata;

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public List<Documents> doc1 { get; set; }
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        //blobから設定ファイルをダウンロードする。
        //storageAccountの作成（接続情報の定義）
        //アカウントネームやキー情報はAzureポータルから確認できる。
        var accountName = "";
        var accessKey = "";
        var credential = new 
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(accountName, accessKey);
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credential, true);
        //blob
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("");


        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "filename"
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference("FILES-1000000.xml");

        string files2;
        using (var memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blockBlob2.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream2);
            files2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream2.ToArray());
        }

        // convert string to stream
        byte[] byteArray2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(files2);
        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
        MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream(byteArray2);
        // convert stream to string
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(filelists));
        filelists result = null;
        result = (filelists)serializer.Deserialize(reader2);
        reader2.Close();
        string data = "";


        for (int i = 0; i <= result.list.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            //result.list[i].file
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob3 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(result.list[0].file);
            using (var memoryStream3 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    await blockBlob3.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream3);
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream3.ToArray());
                    var doc = data.Split("<seprt>");
                    var counter = 0;
                    string id = "";
                    string tytle = "";
                    string body = "";
                    string htmlbody = "";
                    foreach (string value in doc)
                    {
                        if (counter % 4 == 0)
                        {
                            id = doc[counter];
                        }
                        if (counter % 4 == 1)
                        {
                            tytle = doc[counter];
                        }
                        if (counter % 4 == 2)
                        {
                            body = doc[counter];
                        }
                        if (counter % 4 == 3)
                        {
                            htmlbody = doc[counter];
                            //error = id + tytle + body + htmlbody;
                            doc1.Add(new Documents()
                            {
                                id = id,
                                tytle = tytle,
                                body = body,
                                htmlbody = htmlbody,
                            });
                        }
                        counter += 1;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        error = "open";


    }
    // OnPost return type is JsonResult 
    public async Task<JsonResult> OnPost()
    {
        indx = Request.Form["indx"];
        evnt = Request.Form["evnt"];
        textdata = Request.Form["textbody"];
        htmldata = Request.Form["htmlbody"];

        //blobから設定ファイルをダウンロードする。
        //storageAccountの作成（接続情報の定義）
        //アカウントネームやキー情報はAzureポータルから確認できる。
        var accountName = "";
        var accessKey = "";
        var credential = new 
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(accountName, accessKey);
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credential, true);
        //blob
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "filename"
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("");

        string files;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            files = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        // convert string to stream
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(files);
        //byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        // convert stream to string
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(filelists));
        filelists result = null;
        result = (filelists)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        string data = "";
        bodyelement = "";
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob2 = container.GetBlockBlobReference(result.list[0].file);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blockBlob2.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            var doc = data.Split("<seprt>");
            if (evnt == "listclick")
            {
                bodyelement = doc[3 + (Int32.Parse(indx)) * 4];
            }
            else if (evnt == "save")
            {
                doc[2 + (Int32.Parse(indx)) * 4] = textdata;
                doc[3 + (Int32.Parse(indx)) * 4] = htmldata;
                //bodyelement = textdata + htmldata;

                saveDoc(doc);
                bodyelement = "saved";
            }
        }



        await Task.Delay(100);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return new JsonResult("JSONResponse: Error occurred. Please retry.");

        }
        return new JsonResult(bodyelement);
    }
    public async void saveDoc(String[] doc)
    {

        var CSV = "";
        var counter = 0;
        foreach (string value in doc)
        {
            if (counter != doc.Length)
            {
                CSV = CSV + doc[counter] + "<seprt>";
            }
            else
            {
                CSV = CSV + doc[counter];
            }
            counter += 1;
        }
        //blobから設定ファイルをダウンロードする。
        //storageAccountの作成（接続情報の定義）
        //アカウントネームやキー情報はAzureポータルから確認できる。
        var accountName = "";
        var accessKey = "";
        var credential = new 
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(accountName, accessKey);
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credential, true);
        //blob
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("documentsdata");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "filename"
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("C#-1000000.csv");

        var options = new BlobRequestOptions()
        {
            ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
        };
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(CSV), false))
        {
           await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        }

    }

    // 
    /// <remarks/>
    /// 
    public class Itempost
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
    public class SendEmailRequest
    {
        public int PortraitId { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public List<int> FileIds { get; set; }
    }


    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class filelists
    {

        private filelistsEntry[] listField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("entry", IsNullable = false)]
        public filelistsEntry[] list
        {
            get
            {
                return this.listField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.listField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class filelistsEntry
    {

        private string fileField;

        private byte keyField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public string file
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fileField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fileField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte key
        {
            get
            {
                return this.keyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.keyField = value;
            }
        }
    }


 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

change public List doc1 = new List();
to  public static List doc1 = new List();
solved problem.